# How can I save the content inside an html frame that pops up when a link is clicked using greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, save, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I need to automate a process that involves getting data from a series of links on a website.
Greasemonkey could do the job, but I can't get the content from inside that link.

The link looks like this:

```
<a id="ctl00_main_gvPolite_ctl02_lbDetaliiPolita" title="Detalii polita" class="icon16 icon-detalii" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$main$gvPolite$ctl02$lbDetaliiPolita','')"></a>
```

This would be the important part: javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$main$gvPolite$ctl02$lbDetaliiPolita','')

I can't find that function defined anywhere in the javascript, it's only used at various points.

A frame pops up over the website displaying the content I need. After I get it in a variable I can just send it to a script on my server for processing.

Comment: The `__doPostBack` function is generated by ASP.NET pages. It's defined in the page itself, so search for it.

Comment: Wow, that was fast and easy. I found the function and the form it processes. Now I only need to input the right values for each session. That should be easy enough. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it's not as simple as I thought. I got everything going but the resulting page is an error notification instead of the content: "Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster." What can I do to get past this ?

Comment: `__doPostBack` sends informations to the server that make it acknowledge the active session and the current state. And that includes not only the key that you see in the link, but also data like cookies and other form fields in the page. I'm not an expert in ASP.NET, so I think you should make another question about what you should do to emulate a postback using an AJAX request with Grasemonkey (which is a bit different than a common `XMLHttpRequest`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I was missing an input called __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED
It's further down the page in the source code, just include it in your $.post(); or whatever you use and it will work.

All credit goes to MaxArt for this one. Thank you!